# PHP: Possible to trickle-output to browser while waiting for database query to execute?

Tags: php, multithreading

**tl;dr:** Is it possible to feed some "dummy spaces" periodically back to the browser while waiting for a SQL query to execute? This to not have the browser hang up on me while nothing returns.

*Longer story:*

I've made a small "web tool" against a database (MS SQL, using their PDO driver).

Sometimes, the queries that I run take a long time.

After about 100 seconds, the browser just stops "rotating". I don't know yet what causes this, but it is the same with Firefox and Chrome. The stack is PHP 5.3, IIS 6, FastCGI. It is not PHP nor DB/SQLSRV timeout, as I've increased both of those - and other queries I have take a longer time to feed back all the result. (I can reproduce the problem by writing some header, chilling for 110 seconds, and then write the footer. Only the header-part is then shown.)

The problem with the present query, is that it doesn't feed back anything for about 200 seconds, then the whole thing comes. But this doesn't help when something along that stack have stopped listening/receiving/transmitting after about 100 seconds.

**Thus, the question**: Is it possible to trickle-feed the browser some dummy spaces *while* the script is waiting for the SQL to return? In my native tounge of Java, this would be trivial, but in PHP, one is AFAIK utterly single threaded (actually, "single process'd"). I know that this trickling would work, as I have other scripts that in total takes much longer, but which continually sends small pieces of the result back to the browser - this renders just fine.

Comment: No. PHP is not multithreaded. The database query function call will block the script until the query returns data or the whole thing times out. There's no way to fire off another thread to allow for this trickle using PHP.

Comment: @MarcB But you buffer the output.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett: buffering would prevent output as well. in fact, for 'trickle' updates, you want buffering disabled so any output gets sent to the client as soon as possible.

Comment: Ah, I wrote that wrong. You can *flush* the *output buffer*. :)

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for commenting - but I believe the question hints towards me knowing what the problem actually is. I wanted to know about any tricks I have not thought about!

Answer (score 2):

Not if you only intend to run one query. However, depending on the nature of your query, you can probably just split it up into multiple smaller queries, and then loop through those.

Contrary to your other answers and comments, you CAN "trickle-feed" data to the browser, if your split your calls up. You're looking for the `flush()` function.

**DEMO**

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 200; $i++)
{
    sleep(1);
    echo ' ';

    flush();
}

echo 'It worked!';
?>
```

Try running this. It should take 200 seconds. However, because `flush()` is there, it'll send data to the browser after each iteration of the loop, and hopefully not time out! My boss's web host times out after 30 seconds of inactivity (Rackspace, grrrr!) so I've had to use this very same trick countless times.

Comment: Thanks for answering - but I specifically pointed out that I do know how to tricle to the browser. ;-) The problem is that I want to execute a long-running SQL while keeping the browser happy. I cannot split the SQL.

Comment: Here's a way: Let the main script "URL-request" another script that does the long-running task. Do a timed read from this request in a loop, outputting some spaces to the browser on each read that doesn't return the result (trickling the browser). When the result finally arrives from that request, send it to the browser. Thus, "faking" a forked thread. Or, in particular when running on Linux, run a shell-exec. However, I was hoping for some better way for this particular scenario.

Comment: If that actually solves your issue, great! I'm surprised that'd keep the URL-request script running, though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not send output to the browser as you  echo it. It writes the contents to a buffer, and sends the entire contents to the browser at once. So, no, you cannot trickle output to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

flush doesn't work very well there is a better way - you can pipe the output to a file and then use a independent php script to only ever rip the last line, then use ajax on the client to poll that independent script every 200ms the last line. this gives the effect you want I am working on it now and will get the code here ready when I do

EDIT1: HAHa Endre it's you! <3 from England you little athiest you x

EDIT2: the timeout comes from a plethora of subtle params in and out of PHP.ini, mostly undocumented in the sense they seem to be unrelated, but also do *NOT* underestimate the browser being lame - in my experience I was only ever able to irradiate timeouts utterly once and only then on firefox but I *was* able to run/poll a 3 hour long script this way (sadly it was a AD migration script, at my old job and I don't have the code)

EDIT3: you can "thread" in PHP by using the PHP CLI and then the process ID or by using curl both are fairly ewww but you CAN do it